# _changes for a view

Tags: couchdb, couchapp

I have a couchapp.

Client-side, I'm displaying the 10 first results of a `hot` view:

```
GET /_design/superapp/_view/hot?skip=0&limit=10
```

--

How to listen for the [_changes](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/notifications.html) of the first 10 results **of that view**?
I tried with:

```
GET /_changes?feed=continuous&_view=superapp/hot&skip=0&limit=10
```

but it does not seem to work: it appears I've got all updates, neither limited to that view nor to the 10 first results...

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Currently, with 1.1 release you may only use [views as filters](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/commit/56086f07c425bd272bda5a6609ed9db3758178ba) for changes feed - there is no feature to listen changes of views *yet*. [Refuge](http://refuge.io/), the CouchDB fork, has feature to listen [views changes](http://lists.refuge.io/refuge/0154.html), but I'm not sure that it able to handle all views query parameters such as startkey/endkey etc.

Comment: :/ it's bad news... I'm currently using 1.2 on iriscouch.com -- but thx for your answer +1

Comment: Not so bad. You just need to request views periodically and, if Etag header had changed so view had been updated and you could process his top N values.

Comment: You mean without using _changes at all? Just querying `/_design/superapp/_view/hot`?

Comment: Yes. In case if you need to filter results somehow you still have to fallback from `_changes` to `_view` since changes feed filters will process *all* database changes for each your request while views are already precomputed and will return result instantly. Of course, you could optimize `_changes` usage by storing seq value (to start for next request) and previous result (to update on changes), but imho views usage will be much more simpler in this way.